# Quarkus: Overwrite DEV profile config with empty values for Postgres properties

Tags: properties, yaml, quarkus

I'm using Quarkus (2.7.3.Final) with Postgres (`quarkus-jdbc-postgresql`).

And I really like Quarkus' approach that if you configure no `username`, `password` and `url` for your datasource it will try to start a testcontainer and emulate the database, when you start the app in [development mode](https://quarkus.io/guides/getting-started#development-mode).

So for example if you define this in your `application.yml` (or `application.properties`), Quarkus will start a Postgres testcontainer for you, when you start the app with `./mvnw clean quarkus:dev`:

```
quarkus:
  datasource:
    username:
    password:
    db-kind: postgresql
    jdbc:
      driver: org.postgresql.Driver
      url:
```

The log says "`Dev Services for the default datasource (postgresql) started.`"
Pretty neat! :-)

However, what I really want is to define my real/productive database connection settings in my `application.yml`. And then overwrite them in the `application-dev.yml`, so that only in the development mode the testcontainer is started:

- `application.yml` with **PROD** settings:

```
    quarkus:
      datasource:
        username: myuser
        password: mypassword
        db-kind: postgresql
        jdbc:
          driver: org.postgresql.Driver
          url: jdbc:postgresql://hostname:5432/mydb
```

- `application-dev.yml` with **DEV** settings:

```
    quarkus:
      datasource:
        username:
        password:
        jdbc:
          url:
```

But overwriting the properties with `null` values doesn't work, when I start the app in development mode I get the error:

```
Datasource '<default>': Connection to hostname:5432 refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections.
```

The overwriting itself works, if I change my `application-dev.yml` to use an embedded H2 instead of the implicit testcontainer, the application starts:

- `application-dev.yml` with H2 settings:

```
    quarkus:
      datasource:
        username: sa
        password: mypassword
        db-kind: h2
        jdbc:
          driver: org.h2.Driver
          url: jdbc:h2:mem:mydb;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1
```

So my question is: How can I overwrite my datasource configuration with null values, so that Quarkus uses testcontainers in dev mode?

And by the way, switching from a `application.yml` to Quarkus default `application.properties` unfortunately did not help.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Defining the connection settings only in the `prod` profile should help. In the `.properties` format, that would look like `%prod.quarkus.datasource.xxx`, I'm sure you'll know how to translate that to YAML.

Comment: Great idea, thanks. I finally changed it as @ryfterek proposed, but using the prod profile is definitely the correct hint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to complete this: Combining the previous answers and comments using the *prod* profile this my solution:

- `application.yml` with **DEV** settings:

```
    quarkus:
      datasource:
        username:
        password:
        db-kind: postgresql
        jdbc:
          driver: org.postgresql.Driver
          url:
```

- `application-prod.yml` with **PROD** settings:

```
    quarkus:
      datasource:
        username: myuser
        password: mypassword
        jdbc:
          url: jdbc:postgresql://hostname:5432/mydb
```

The `application-dev.yml` isn't needed this way. Thanks folks! :-)

Answer (score 0):

Following [Quarkus' official documentation](https://quarkus.io/guides/config-reference#profile-in-the-property-name),

> If a profile does not define a value for a specific attribute, the
> default (no profile) value is used

This behaviour will be useful in many cases, but in yours might lead to the inability to override properties once defined in the default profile back to their empty state.

I would suggest you to swap your profiles around i.e. treat the null-valued `dev` configuration as a default and provide meaningful non-null `prod` values in an overriding profile.

If you are worried that `dev` values might be used this way accidentally in `prod` environment, remember that [Quarkus is going to use `prod` profile by default if not told otherwise.](https://quarkus.io/guides/config-reference#default-profiles)

Comment: Thanks a lot, this works! :-) 
I'll add my final implementation below just in case anyone needs a practical example.

Comment: @ChristianSchwörer you're welcome. Consider marking either the helpful response or your own final summary as the accepted answer to let the community know your problem has been solved. :)